# Adjust view size in accordance with screen size

Tags: android-studio

I am having problem in resizing views according to screen size changes in android studio. I have 3 image buttons adjacent to each other and I want their combined width to fill width of screen. I know that match_parent can fill the screen size but this case is different. I want each button of width as 1/3 size of screen. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these 3 buttons are located inside a horizontal `<LinearLayout>` add these tags to each button `layout_width="0dp"` and `layout_weight="1"`

Comment: I have buttons in relative layout. Actually I have 9 buttons with 3 in each row and all 9 are in same relative layout. What should I do?

Comment: If i were you i would have a main `<LinearLayout>` that has an orientation of vertical, then put 3 more linear layouts under it, each linear layout with specify `layout_height="0dp"` and `layout_weight="1"`, then each button inside the linear layouts have the code specified above

Comment: Actually I have 3x3 layout structure so so can I use grid layout instead out relative layout? Would grid layout arrange its childs according to screen size?

Comment: GridLayout would probably be the best practice, but the LinearLayouts will work also, I don't think there will be any performance impact on using the nested LinearLayouts for this example though. I'm not sure if you can have the children in a GridLayout fill the cell, I don't have alot of experience with GridLayouts